# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

even though I have the required selenium-api in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help before I shoot myself.

Comment: The solution here (the first answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010767/selenium-java-4-1-3-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-webdrive worked.